# can we access "sysfs entry" in our android application directly?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, sysfs

I know that we are using jni as an interface with driver which allows android application framework to communicate with device driver.

But i don't know exact reason that why we can't access those sysfs entries in our application directly?

Please explain in detail.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot access sysfs from application layer. I was trying to perform write on a sysfs file but failed.

Have to necessarily go through android middleware framework and/or HAL layer. These services could be provided selinux privileges allowing access to sysfs.