# How to Access sysfs entry from android application

Tags: android, apk, sysfs

Can someone please explain to me on `how to access a value exposed by sysfs from an android application.`

A reference which suggests that we can not access is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653453/can-we-access-sysfs-entry-in-our-android-application-directly)

But there is one [android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.kiljacken.sfe&hl=en) which does the same.

Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after some research

This is how it works.

```
//cmd will be the path of script to be executed
String cmd = "/home_dir/./my_shell_script.sh" ; 
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime() ; 
//this will run the script from java
Process pr = run.exec(cmd) ;
```

The values returned can be read like this

```
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
try {
        String string = buf.readLine();
        char[] text = string.toCharArray();
        int start = 0;
        int len = string.length();
        textView.setText(text, start, len);
        Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

It will show the variable/output in a toast message.

References:

1 [Executing shell command from java](http://www.example.com/)

2 [/sys/devices/virtual/gpio access from Java?](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/android-porting/sysfs%2420jni/android-porting/toRX0SOcy-k/aUItPROKlBEJ)

Please let me know if there are any other methods for this.

Comment: can you plz paste wht you are doing in the shell script !